# serialization a class in C++

Tags: c++, serialization

I need to have a way to serialize classes in my code into a string. Later on, using that string I would need to populate an instance of that class.

i.e.

```
enum AlarmStatus
{
   Clear=0,
   Active
};

class AlarmInfo
{
public:
std::string S;
int I;
AlarmStatus alarmStatus;
void setAlarmStatus(AlarmStatus alarmStatus);
AlarmStatus getAlarmStatus();
};
```

Any ideas how I can do that in code? I know boost have boost/archive/ library that can serialize a class but it is not a "HeaderOnly library"? Is there a library that is Header only?

Thank you

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: If you want to do it entirely on your own, you can overload `operator<<` to serialize and `operator>>` to deserialize -- but go to/from a stream, not a string directly (use stringstream when you want a string). Probably cleaner to start from [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) though.

Comment: also, http://serialisemycode.com

Comment: I found a few by typing for "serialize [c++]" in the search bar at the top of the page. Which ones have you tried already?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?? I did my research and I did find few libraries, I just thought it should be something simple and don't need libraries to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a to and from serial code and call that

```
struct Person{
  string name;
  int age;

  void toSerial(ostream& stream){ stream << name << age; }
  void fromSerial(istream& stream){  stream >> name >> age; }
}

int main(){
  Person person;
  //save to data.txt
  ofstream fileOut("data.txt");      
  person.toSerial(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();

  //load from data.txt
  ifstream fileIn("data.txt");
  person.fromSerial(fileIn);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have reflection. Therefore, features like some other programming languages provide, like C#'s `BinaryFormatter`, `XmlSerializer`, or `DataContractSerializer` are not possible to implement. You have to implement serialization yourself.

(Personally, I think this is a good thing. Your file format shouldn't be so coupled to your implementation because some time later you'll want to change implementation. And then find out you're screwed because your file format is defined in terms of that code)